# What is wrong with my MultiPartFormData Encoder? Swift 4

Tags: swift, request, header, multipartform-data

Hello) This is my MultiPartFormDataEncoder:

```swift
            let boundary =  "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

            var body = ""

            if let parameters = parameters {
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
                    body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(String(describing: key))\"\r\n\r\n"
                    body += "\(String(describing: value))\r\n"
                }
            }

            if let files = files {
                for file in files {
                    body += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
                    body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(file.key)\"; filename=\"\(file.name)\"\r\n"
                    body += "Content-Type: \(file.type)\r\n\r\n"
                    body += "\(file.data)\r\n"
                }
            }

            body += "--".appending(boundary.appending("--"))

            urlRequest.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)

            if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
                urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; charset=utf8; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            }
            urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 60
            urlRequest.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
```

After sending request to server I getting "Bad Request". When I try to do that in postman request is success.
All parameters and files have correct names, types and keys. I checked a for sure.
So problem is not in BackEnd because it get my request and see correct body but it breaks after getting.

I think it is something wrong with headers.

So, what do you think?

Edit:
After correct response parsing I see next message:

{"image":["Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."]}

Comment: `body += "\(file.data)\r\n"` What's that exactly? What's the output of `"\(file.data)\r\n"`? What's `file.data`? Also `urlRequest.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)` doing it at the end is usually not recommended, becase usually you don't put a String file, you put data piece by piece, some are coming from String (via utf8 encoding), but other aren't, like the file data.

Comment: @Larme file.data is just Data(), for example jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.99). I was try put data piece by piece, but it didn't help. (

Comment: And what do tou expect the output be? Does it seem valid to you?

Comment: Stop thinking "Data can be translated into UTF8 String" and vice-versa. Stop thinking that anything using String interpolation: "\(something)" is the solution. Instead, use something like that: https://pastebin.com/07e8GBeF

Comment: Server(Django Rest Framework) see body correct <QueryDict: {'names':["['Fransdval']"], 'image':[<InMemoryUploadedFile: test_image.jpg (image/jpg)>]}>
and the same from postman, but my request is bad and from postman is success. Maybe something in headers?

Comment: Note that Postman can generate Swift code to help you see the differences between the working request and the working one.

Comment: @Larme pastebin.com/07e8GBeF - the same bad request(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found problem and solution.

Error was in this line:

```swift
body += "\(file.data)\r\n"
```

As says [@Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme), we can't put data and string in one line.

Better **solution** will be add data and string separately, for example:

```swift
// old body += "\(file.data)\r\n"

// new:
var body: Data = Data()

body.append(file.data)
body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

---

**In my case MultiPartFormDataParameterEncoder will look like:**

```swift
func encode(urlRequest: inout URLRequest, with parameters: Parameters?, files: Files?) throws {
        do {
            let boundary =  "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

            var body: Data = Data()

            if let parameters = parameters {
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    try body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                    try body.appendString("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(String(describing: key))\"\r\n\r\n")
                    try body.appendString("\(String(describing: value))\r\n")
                }
            }

            if let files = files {
                for file in files {
                    try body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                    try body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(file.key)\"; filename=\"\(file.name)\"\r\n")
                    try body.appendString("Content-Type: \"\(file.type)\"\r\n\r\n")
                    body.append(file.data)
                    try body.appendString("\r\n")
                }
            }

            try body.appendString("--".appending(boundary.appending("--")))

            urlRequest.httpBody = body

            if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
                urlRequest.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            }
        } catch {
            throw NetworkError.encodingMultiPartFormDataFailed
        }
    }

public enum NetworkError: String, Error {
    case encodingMultiPartFormDataFailed = "Parameter encoding in MultiPartFormData failed ..."
}
```

Also have to add Files and Parameters models:

```swift
public typealias Parameters = [String:Any]
public typealias Files = [FileModel]

public struct FileModel {
    let name: String
    let key: String
    let data: Data
    let type: String

    init(name: String, type: FileType, data: Data) {
        self.name = name
        self.key = type.key // will be image or audio
        self.data = data
        self.type = type.rawValue // will be "audio/mp3" or "image/jpeg"
    }
}

extension FileModel {
    enum FileType: String {
        case image = "image/jpeg"
        case audio = "audio/mp3"

        var key: String {
            return String(describing: self)
        }
    }
}

// USAGE EXAMPLE
FileModel(name: name, type: .image, data: imageJpegData)
```

Also don't forgot Data extension to make more safety:

```swift
extension Data {
    private enum DataError: String, Error {
        case encodingStringToDataFailed = "Encoding String to Data failed ..."
    }

    mutating func appendString(_ string: String) throws {
        guard let data: Data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
            throw DataError.encodingStringToDataFailed
        }
        append(data)
    }
}
```

**Thanks ^_^**